# Python send <\n> over tcp socket

Tags: python, encoding, tcp

We have a string which should be send to a service via a websocket. This string containt some data which is seperated by some tags. One row of data always ends with `<\r><\n>`.

So we want to send each row of data to this service which is implemented as a TCPServer. This is working perfectly fine in case we use normal strings, but as soon as we try to incorporate the tags I mentioned, Python just keeps appending them in the infinite loop and sends them as one huge string when the loop is exited:

Consider the following implementation:

```
import random
from datetime import datetime
import time
import socket
import sys

HOST = "xx.xx.xx.xx"
PORT = 12345
srv = (HOST, PORT)

cls = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0)
cls.connect(srv)


# DATA:



# Variable to change status text
dec = 0
while 1:
   
    data = "foo\\nbar"
    size = cls.send(data.encode())
    print(size)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Then the string is built up in python until I quit the loop manually to: `foo\\nbarfoo\\nbarfoo\\nbarfoo\\nbarfoo\\nbarfoo\\nbarfoo\\nbar` and sent to the socket.

What we want to accomplish is, that those strings are sent after each other like:

```
foo\nbar
foo\nbar
foo\nbar
```

Is there any possibility to send those special characters with the string together?

Comment: Add \\, "\" is an escape caracter, so "\\" is really "\", so you want "\\\\" to get "\\"

Comment: I need just one \

Comment: What the caracter that pose problem ?

Comment: I don't know what you really want to set. If you want to send new line then use simply string `"\r\n"`. OR: usually `\r\n` means chars with hex cods `0xA`, `0xD` and you can send these values as bytes. If you want to send tag `<\n>` then you have to use double \\ - `<\\n>`. For socket it only string, nothing more.